# How can I structure a Sequelize.js schema that will need complex joins?

Tags: mysql, join, database-schema, sequelize.js

I have a `Reviews` table that has a `SceneId`. A `Scene` model has a `MovieId` which refers to a `Movie`. Now if I want to get all `Reviews` that belong to some `Movie`, should I duplicate the `MovieId` in `Review` or should I do some crazy complex join? Are there performance implications of either?

If I am to use a crazy complex join, how would I do it within the Sequelize ORM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on how often you are going to run the query, and the performance you want.

If you are going to have lots and lots of data, and / or you are going to run the query often, then adding a movieId in Review would probably be a good idea. This will give you better performance, because you don't have to join through an extra table.

However, it also means you will have to do some more bookkeeping yourself to ensure that the movieid of a Review always matches the movieid in Scene. This could probably be achieved using hooks in sequelize.

To do the join you would do:

```
Scene.belongsTo(Movie)
Movie.hasMany(Scene)

Review.belongsTo(Scene)
Scene.hasMany(Review)

Movie.findAll({
    include: [
        { Model: Scene, include: [Review] }
    ]
});
```

The approach using JOINs means you will then have to go through each scene and collects the reviews to get all reviews for the movie, something like:

```
var reviews = movies.scenes.map(function (scene) {
    return scene.reviews
);
// Now we have an array of arrays of reviews

// Let's merge those into one:
reviews = Array.prototype.concat([], reviews);
```

Whereas if you denormalize you can simply do

```
Review.belongsTo(Movie) // add movieId to review

Movie.findAll({
    include: [
        Scene,
        Review
    ]
});
```

And access `movie.reviews` directly